# Jquery split() is not a function?

Tags: jquery, split

Not sure at all why this doesn't work.

```
var jimmy = $.get("info.txt");
jimmy = jimmy.split("\n");
```

Why does it have to be like this:

```
$.get("info.txt", function(jimmy) {
    jimmy = jimmy.split("\n");
});
```

The second way works fine, but it would make things easier if I could do it the first way, and I'm not sure why it can't be done. It's very different to php.

Comment: When you're working with AJAX, you may find it useful to use callback functions defined separately, and move your execution logic to those callback functions.  It does require a different way of thinking about the problem, but can help you avoid horrible nesting problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out in your developer tools:

```
var jimmy = $.get("info.txt"); console.log(jimmy);
```

You will see that jimmy will have javascript info(callbacks) on what this $.get is doing and what the response will be. That is a lot more information you want, you only want the response data.
Another thing with the first option is that the second line is already executed before the response is back, because $.get is asynchronous.

That is why the second option is working. Only when info.txt is loaded it will execute what is inside of the get function(callback). So only then the information can be read.

To make it global you do like this.

```
var sjors = '';
$.get("info.txt", function(jimmy) {
    sjors = jimmy.split("\n");
});
```

A global variable is created when outside a function. Now sjors will be a global variable with the content of jimmy.

Comment: $.get is an asynchronous call.  You can do Asynchronous calls in PHP as well, such as with forking or cURL requests, which may be more common.  However, the reason it doesn't work is due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX. I suggest changing the PHP reference to be more accurate.

Comment: So that means you can never grab data from a file and assign it to a global variable? Seems very limiting.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is an asynchronous function, it means that it doesn't return the results immediately. You need to provide it a "callback" function, which will be run after the AJAX GET request has completed.

Answer (score 0):

The request takes time, of course, so it won't be retrieved immediately.

What you can do is

```
$.get("info.txt", function(jimmy) {
    window.jimmy = jimmy.split("\n");
});
```

Then it can be accessed as `jimmy`